# Custom card component using Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I think I'm quite close to getting it right but the problem I'm having right now is that the texts overflow when the screen gets really small..which is unlikely to happen but I want to fix it so that the texts will never overflow out of the box.

How can I achieve that?

Here's my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q3vue7wy/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 7.75rem;
  transition: all 300ms;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: solid 1px #F5F5F5;
}

.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 1.1825rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.price {
  color: #BAA082;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media(min-width: 46.5rem) {
  .wrapper {
    height: 8.75rem;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 1.1875rem;
  }
  .price {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="title">Point of sale</h4>
    <p>Point of sale</p>
    <p class="price">From £165</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior do you want when the screen gets too small? Do you expect it to hide the overflowing text? Or do you want the image to appear above or below the text? There are many ways to fix this.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 I suppose it will always stay a two-column card. I tried making the main wrapper `height: auto; min-height: 7.75rem` but then the image container becomes really small even though I've set it to `height: auto` instead of following the wrapper

Comment: Did you tried `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` so a scroll bar appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to make the image width shrink when the card gets too small. To do this, change the following properties:

```css
.wrapper {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 1 33%;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Which should give:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 7.75rem;
  transition: all 300ms;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: solid 1px #F5F5F5;
}

.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 1 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 1.1825rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.price {
  color: #BAA082;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media(min-width: 46.5rem) {
  .wrapper {
    height: 8.75rem;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 1.1875rem;
  }
  .price {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="title">Point of sale</h4>
    <p>Point of sale</p>
    <p class="price">From £165</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wq1cev3y/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**- Replace the below code to your HTML code

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
  <h4 class="title">
   Point of sale
  </h4>
  <p class="dec">
   Point of sale
  </p>
  <p class="price">
   From £165
  </p>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" class="image">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**- Replace the below code to your media query code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
 .wrapper{
  height: 8.75rem;
 }
 .title{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:8%;
 }
 .dec{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:8%;
 }
 .price{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:8%;
 }
}
```